# Com interface c++ structure size limits

Tags: c++, interface, com

I have a server COM interface written in c++. Now I have a structure that have an array of structures each with an array of structures inside. All these arrays have fixed sizes.

```
 const int infosize        = 32;
 const int count           = 8;
 const int cmax            = 32;

 typedef enum cstate {
     NotValidated,
     Approved,
     Rejected,
     ValidationStateCount
 } cstate;

 typedef struct inner {
     int     type;
     char    value[ infosize ];
 } inner;

 typedef struct middle {
     int        mtype;
     cstate     state;
     char       name[ infosize ];
     inner      infoArr[ count ];
 } middle;

 typedef struct outer {
     char        model[ infosize ];
     char        cname[ infosize ];
     UINT        rcount;
     middle      cmiddle[ cmax ];
 } outer;
```

This have worked perfecty well until now.
However when I increase the size of the array in the outer structure cmax to 33 it suddenly stops working.
The size of the total structure is around 10 kBytes.
Is there some limit for the size of a structure transferred over a COM interface?

The code is

```
STDMETHODIMP Server::GetInformation( outer* compInfo, ResCode* result )
{
    if ( result == nullptr )
    {
        return E_POINTER;
    }

    *result = GetInformation( compInfo );
    return S_OK;
}
```

Do I need a CComSafeArray to put my structure into?

Comment: The COM interface defines the types it expects. You cannot simply change it and hope for everything to work out. The fact that it **appears** to *"have worked perfecty well until now"* is no indication of correctness. The behavior is undefined, and appearing to work is a valid form of undefined behavior. Without code there's nothing we can do, though, except pointing out, that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: please explain what exactly stops working: server side/client side, which code fails with which error

Comment: I wonder what your MIDL looks like for the `GetInformation` signature. Surely, with `outer` not being an integral data type, it must be introduced to MIDL. And once that is done, it becomes immutable. So you violated one of two rules: You used an incompatible data type in an interface member signature, or you changed the size or layout of a data type after it was published. You need to get a good book, [Essential COM](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201634465) by Don Box will do.

Comment: I got it working now. The problem was that I was remote debugging on the server and I forgot to register thte updates of the structure..

Comment: That sounds wrong. A COM interface is immutable. Once published, you cannot change an interface. If you change an interface, you will have to assign a new GUID. Since your code silently failed, you probably violated that COM rule as well.